# How to provide Room Dao dependency using Dagger2 for Android?

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-2

My repository passes in a Room Persistence lib. Dao object as a dependency. The problem is Dao is an interface. The most recent suggestion by Google is to do the following:

```
// Tells Dagger this is a Dagger module
// Because of @Binds, StorageModule needs to be an abstract class
@Module
abstract class StorageModule {

    // Makes Dagger provide SharedPreferencesStorage when a Storage type is requested
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideStorage(storage: SharedPreferencesStorage): Storage
}
```

In the example above, `SharedPreferencesStorage` is a user created implementation of the interface, `Storage`. The problem with Room dao dependencies is that the implementation is generated by the library like `roomDatabase.getDatabase(context).myDao()`. The most recent Dagger version seems to avoid using the old way of passing in component dependencies through a module constructor. Is there a way to do this using `@Subcomponent.Factory` or `@Component.Factory`, or is the "old" way the only way to do this for Room dao dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following approach:

```
@Module
class DatabaseModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideDaoA(db: MyDb): DaoA = db.daoA()

    @Provides
    fun provideDaoB(db: MyDb): DaoB = db.daoB()
}

class MyRepository @Inject constructor(private val daoA: DaoA) {..}
```

Another approach [from googlesamples](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dagger-android/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/di/ApplicationModule.kt#L56-L67):

```
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @TasksLocalDataSource
    @Provides
    fun provideTasksLocalDataSource(
        database: ToDoDatabase,
        ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ): TasksDataSource {
        return TasksLocalDataSource(
            database.taskDao(), ioDispatcher
        )
    }
```